# How to perform a click on DataGridRow using UIAutomation (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, ui-automation

I can perform a selection on DataGridRow (WPF). However, When a row is selected, I can't perform a click on it.

Here is my code:

```
 AutomationElement a = UiElement.AutomationElement;     
 var DataGridRowsCondition = new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "DataGridRow");
 var DataGridRows = a.FindAll(TreeScope.Subtree, DataGridRowsCondition);
 (DataGridRows[2].GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern).Select();
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'when selected,can't perform a click on it"?

Comment: You need to ensure that each row and each clickable control has a unique automation ID - without that you can't execute automateable actions.

Comment: @zackraiyan  selected row it means that row is highlighted and focused when it selected on DataGrid.

Comment: @slugster Thank you, I've tried to get clickable point but it's null so I think that could be the main problem here.